# How to get the window handle for a VBA MsgBox?

Tags: c#, vba, excel, windows-7

I'm running a C# script on a large number of Excel workbooks that involves calling a macro in each workbook; the macro sometimes produces a MsgBox because of an error handler, and that pauses execution of the script until I click "OK" in the MsgBox.

The title text of the MsgBox is "Error in processSub", and the main text is "Error (Type Mismatch)".

I thought maybe I could have a concurrent thread that finds all currently open windows, and if it finds the MsgBox, clicks "OK".  I'm trying to find the window using something like this:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
public Process getErrorWindow()
    {
        Process[] processList = Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (Process process in processList)
        {

            if (process.MainWindowTitle=="Error in processSub")
            {
                return process;
            }
        }

    }
```

But this doesn't find anything.  When I look through `processList[]`, it only seems to find the main Excel window, and not any of the child windows that its VBA code produces.  Is there a way to find the MsgBox and click its OK button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the winapi function [FindWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499(v=vs.85).aspx) to retrieve the handle of a window by its title and class. Add the following code to your program:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

public static IntPtr FindExcelErrorPopup()
{
    return FindWindow(null, "Error in processSub");
}
```

To click the button:

```
IntPtr hwnd = FindExcelErrorPopup();
if (hwnd != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    SetForegroundWindow(hwnd); // activates the window
    SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}"); // send ENTER key
}
```

If the default button is not "OK", send some TAB strokes to select it before the ENTER.
Don't forget to put `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;` for the `DllImport`.

EDIT:
For remote desktop try this native method:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern void keybd_event(Keys bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);

private const uint KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001;
private const uint KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002;
const uint KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001;
const uint KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002;
```

And raise keys like this:

```
keybd_event(Keys.Enter, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, UIntPtr.Zero); // key down
keybd_event(Keys.Enter, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, UIntPtr.Zero); // key up
```

Comment: This works successfully, but when I run it on a remote desktop, `SendKeys.SendInput()` throws a `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied`.  Any ideas on how to resolve this, since I'll be running the script on a remote desktop so that the process can continue even if I shut down my laptop?

Comment: couldn't you add a try/catch to trap that error and handle it without having windows popping any messagebox?

Comment: If you're doing the whole FindWindow dance anyway, just find the default button and press it. Skip the difficulty of injecting keyboard events. (And if you insist on doing so, you should totally be using SendInput, not keybd_event.)

Comment: I ended up resolving it by running an AutoIt script on the remote machine.